# $this->uri->segment(2) giving me 404 error when in Index function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a users profile section for my website, and the URL would be `/users/handle/`

for some reason when using `$this->uri->segment(2)` it is just sending me to my 404 error page.

The weird thing is, if i change the function to `profiles` and then make it `segment(3)` and go to the url `/users/profile/handle` the code works fine and loads up the right view.

I've tried changing the segment number to 0,1,2 & 3 and neither seem to work when in my users Index function.

Here is the function for my index below.

```
 public function index() {

        $username = trim(strip_tags($this->uri->segment(2)));



        if (!$username) {
            $data['error'] = _('User not found');
            $this->load->view('user-profiles', $data);
        } else {
            $profile = $this->db->get_where("users", ["handle" => $username]);
            $profile = $profile->row();
            $data['profile'] = $profile;


            $this->load->view('user-profiles', $data);

        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to of worked it out.

For anyone else who runs into a similar problem, i edited my routes.php file and added

```
$route['users/(:any)'] = "users/index/$1";
```